# Customizing row spinner when values are fetched from database

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-sqlite

I am retrieving the values from a database with a cursor and display them in a spinner using a simple adapter list!! All's fine, the only thing worrying me is the look I want to customize the spinner's drop-down, I searched a lot, but couldn't get any results as I am using database values!! Let me know if we can customize the drop-down.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, for all the help!! It worked. Not only setting it as background in the xml, I should also set it to setDropDownViewResource() in the java code. and its running.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

[Check out these link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/12/custom-spinner-with-icon.html)

Summary:

row.xml to set up the layout on each row (in this case: one image and text each row):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/icon"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/weekofday"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/new_button"/>//background changing as per selector
</LinearLayout>
```

---

java code sample

```
public class AndroidCustomSpinner extends Activity {

String[] DayOfWeek = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);

   Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
     R.layout.row, R.id.weekofday, DayOfWeek);
   mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
```

---

`Addind Selector to TextView android:bacground="@drawable/new_button" can achieve your background on the basis of selected or focused`
`res/drawable/new_button.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
      android:state_focused="true" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
 </selector>
```

Comment: Proper understanding of cusomizing spinner is availbale @ http://easyandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2012/05/custom-spinner-in-android.html

Comment: I am using an xml file just like this, and I set a background to the text view, which displays the background only for the selected item not the items in drop down list. I want to apply style even for the items in the drop down

Comment: @SwathiRao Adding selector can gave you exactly what you asked for. I've edited the code please go through it.

Comment: I tried out the code, this only displays the bg for the item selected within the spinner. I want a style for the items even within the list!! Say if i have values like car, buses, trains in the list, all the values should have a bg not only the selected item.